# How to do check if ArrayList object

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-paging

I am making a retrofit POST request using Paging library. 
When the first page is loaded the next page is automatically called. 
But when it comes to the last page (assume page 5), it requests for page 6, then on response
the app crash with error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()'` on a null object reference

when it queries for page 6, from my LogCat, an HTTP response is OK with Content length 0. But when i do checking it crashes

```
        //...code
        private final ReplaySubject<Rating> ratingReplaySubject;

        //...code
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Rating>> call, Response<ArrayList<Rating>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                callback.onResult(response.body(), Integer.toString(page.get()+1));
                mutableLiveData.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);

                //First i tried this,
                //response.body().forEach(ratingReplaySubject::onNext);

                //Then I tried this,
                //ArrayList<Rating> ratingArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                //ratingArrayList = response.body();
                //if(ratingArrayList == null && !ratingArrayList.isEmpty()){
                //    for(int i=0; i<ratingArrayList.size(); i++){
                //        ratingReplaySubject.onNext(ratingArrayList.get(i));
                //    }
                //}

            } else {
                mutableLiveData.postValue(new NetworkState(NetworkState.Status.FAILED, response.message()));
                Log.e("API CALL", response.message());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're most likely attempting to call methods on an item that doesn't exist, hence a `NullPointerException`. Check if the page exists before getting it and performing operations on it.

Comment: check list is empty or not before postValue. Where is your logcat? post it

Comment: @AustinSchäfer I can do that, but what if  my number of page is dynamic. Since the number is automatically incremented when last page is retrieved, i just want to check if results null dont do anything

Comment: @MD I updated my question. How do i actually check if it is intantiated?